# Android Studio/Visual Studio (Xamarin.Android) can not move button Acitivity Main

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

[image]

[image]

I can't move a button, or other object in the Activity Main. Can anyone Maybe help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move a button or other control in the main activity, I suggest you can try to change RelativeLayout using LinearLayout, then you can move control in Main activity.

[image]

Comment: i use alle Layouts but Nothing help me. I habe two png in my post. When this help.

Comment: @DerPate2030, you mean that you can not move Button like me when you use LinearLayout? What is the Visual Studio version?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot freely move an element within a RelativeLayout. I think what you want is an AbsoluteLayout (I don't recommend this though). You should learn about android layouts. ([you can try think tutorial as well](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_user_interface_layouts.htm))

Comment: Yeah i know what you mean, but my Problem is i use all this Layouts and not a one of this layout help me a element free to move.

Comment: I have never used the LayoutDesigner myself. But you could use the AbsoluteLayout and the layout_x and layout_y parameters to manually set the offsets. However I would recommend you use other layout types to recreate the same effect (this would make sure different devices show the same layout)